# Youtube API one channel two IDs

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have this YT channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/komercnibanka 
And we are getting info about this channel by calling this API endpoint with this response
Endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&mine=true
```

Response:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "\"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/P8Z5h8r4nizvqkkGrLQw_63AD6s\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "\"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/ieGVg67eLYf2sS8FnvxM5bvlT7Y\"",
            "id": "UCTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw",
            "contentDetails": {
                "relatedPlaylists": {
                    "likes": "LLTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw",
                    "favorites": "FLTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw",
                    "uploads": "UUTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw",
                    "watchHistory": "HL",
                    "watchLater": "WL"
                }
            },
            "statistics": {
                "viewCount": "0",
                "commentCount": "0",
                "subscriberCount": "0",
                "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
                "videoCount": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And there is channel id: `UCTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw`
But when I am trying to get info about video in this channel by calling this endpoint with response 
Endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=a_7sGSviatI
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/lNoo5LQ0iW-1_trvVMg8bmYTxCE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/U8w78JiuS4m5BOdGhmuhl_4iYq0\"",
   "id": "a_7sGSviatI",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2020-01-16T10:00:02.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCCuTLqbEICKevJt4nHZowyQ",
    "title": "Jak se přihlásit do aplikace eTrading pomocí internetového bankovnictví",
    "description": "Návodné video vám ukáže, jak se jednoduše a rychle přihlásit do aplikace KB eTrading.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/a_7sGSviatI/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/a_7sGSviatI/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/a_7sGSviatI/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/a_7sGSviatI/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/a_7sGSviatI/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Komerční banka",
    "categoryId": "24",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Jak se přihlásit do aplikace eTrading pomocí internetového bankovnictví",
     "description": "Návodné video vám ukáže, jak se jednoduše a rychle přihlásit do aplikace KB eTrading."
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1M14S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "51",
    "likeCount": "0",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "0"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And there is channel id: `UCCuTLqbEICKevJt4nHZowyQ`
So now i have two ids for one YT channel.

```
UCTnxNdcLS28y5sFsiop5tDw
UCCuTLqbEICKevJt4nHZowyQ
```

How it is possible?

Comment: This would suggest to me that that video is not in the channel you think it is.

Comment: But I have only one own channel by API